# How do I call functions that reside inside method of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a object already written by other developer which has a method that I want to use. It looks like this:

```
someObject : {

    sampleObject: function {

        function setAd(){
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

I want use/call the `function setAd()` outside of object. Is it possible? I tried but it shows `undefined`

Comment: Nope, not possible. Move it outside.

Comment: if it's written like that it's a private method, just like you might find in C# and other OO languages. So (assuming the developer did it correctly) it's intended not to be called from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. In javascript functions behave like variables. They can be for example hoisted, but more importantly they are bound to a certain scope, where they have been declared and you can call them only there.

You can check out this article on w3schools:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

And also: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp